# qt Keys.onPressed: don't answer for keyboard

Tags: qt, qml

I've got a very strange problem when using Keys.onPressed in a qml, there is no error throughout the compiling as well as executing, but it doesn't execute the function within the case after pressing the keyboard, the code is on the beneath.

I've tried to define the same function in the Keys case as in the mousearea case. But only Clicked mousearea can work,so it's not the problem of the function. And I tried another project using Keys.onPressed so neither the problem of the software. My keyboard works well so I can ask the question here. I've no idea at all.

Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
visible: true
width: 360
height: 560
title: qsTr("2048")

MainForm {
    id: root
    anchors.fill: parent

    property int eN
    property int eM


    function vidergrille() {
        for(eN = 0; eN < 4; eN++) {
            for(eM = 0; eM < 4; eM++) {
                egrille.eNums.itemAt(4*eN+eM).eNum = "";
                egrille.eNums.itemAt(4*eN+eM).color = "white";
            }
        }
    }
    function showgrille() {
        vidergrille();
        for(eN = 0; eN < 4; eN++) {
            for(eM = 0; eM < 4; eM++) {
                if(vueGrille.lireChiffre(eN,eM)) {
                    egrille.eNums.itemAt(4*eN+eM).eNum = vueGrille.lireChiffre(eN,eM);
                    egrille.eNums.itemAt(4*eN+eM).color = vueGrille.color(eN,eM);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Keys.onPressed: {
      switch (event.key) {
        case Qt.Key_Up:
            vueGrille.commencer();
            root.showgrille();
          break;
        case Qt.Key_Down:
            vueGrille.mouveBas();
            root.showgrille();
          break;
        case Qt.Key_Left:
            vueGrille.mouveGauche();
            root.showgrille()
          break;
        case Qt.Key_Right:
            vueGrille.mouveDroite();
            root.showgrille()
          break;
        default:
            break;
      }
    }

    start {
        onClicked:vueGrille.commencer(),root.showgrille();
    }

    back {
        onClicked:vueGrille.mouveHaut(),root.showgrille();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What language is this? Please [edit] the post to tag it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `focus: true` in your MainForm

Comment: Unbelievable!!! Thank you so much !!! I'm a green hand and I don't expect for a so quick answer. Thanks again for your aide !!!

Comment: My pleasure. Have a nice day !